# An example of Newton's Third Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I understand that Newton's Third Law applies to throwing an axe, but I can't draw what force is applied to what.

If I was to bring back the axe to the top of my head, am I applying a force to the axe? And if I was to throw the axe, what force is applied to what?

Throwing an axe example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_rknG9uGTA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the direction you face be 'A' . When you pull or bring back the axe over your head you are applying a force on the axe in the backwards direction ,that is Opposite to direction A. But at the same time as newtons 3rd law says the axe causes a force in the forward direction (direction A). Now when you throw the axe forward your again applying a force on the axe but in the forward direction (I.e. Direction A) and the axe tends a force on you opposite to direction A.
IN SIMPLE-in both the case you are applying a force on the axe and vice versa but only the direction of applied force changes

Comment: Hope the answer was helpful, please vote

Comment: When I'm bringing the axe over my head, I'm applying a force onto the axe or else the axe would fall to the ground. When I throw my axe to the forward direction, I'm applying a force onto the axe to move forward. Then the axe will apply the same amount of force onto me at the same time, right? If the axe was massive enough, I would move back a little after I throw the axe, right?

Comment: @austingae yes! Like the recoils of a gun